# Convert complex Oracle query into Postgre

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle. I want to convert this Oracle query to PostgreSQL. But I do not understand what '*start_date + level-1*' means. What is 'v'? These terms: *LEVEL*, *CONNECT BY* are new to me. I looked at some examples to learn what WITH, CONNECT BY, LEVEL normally mean. However I still don't have any idea how to convert this to postgreSql.

```
WITH t AS
          (
            SELECT start_date + level-1 As date1
            FROM
            (
              SELECT created_at date1, last_date As date2 FROM dual
            ) v
            CONNECT BY date1 + level-1 <= date2
          )
          SELECT ( ..... )
```

I have tablefunc extension in my PostgreDB. Read about this in a few articles. Can someone please briefly explain what's going on here and help me convert this into postgreSql? Also if you could provide any link that clearly explains these terms, that would be greatly beneficial to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Question is level a field in your table?

Comment: `level` is an Oracle keyword for use with its hierarchical query feature. That's the `connect by` syntax. Basically the code you have is an Oracle trick to generate a range of dates between two bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Use `generate_series()`:

```
select date1
from generate_series(created_at, last_date, interval '1 day') gs(date1)
```

Your query doesn't define where the columns come from, but this can often be used as:

```
select t.*, gs.date1
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(t.created_at, t.last_date, interval '1 day') gs(date1)
```

Answer (score 1):

that's counter with oracle specific recursive statement. the above answer gives an alternative way to get it without recursion. if you want recursion, in postgresql you can use recursive CTE, eg:

```
with recursive t1 (date1) as
(select created_at as date1 from dual
union all
select date1+1 as date1
from t1
where date1+1<=last_date)

select * from t1;
```

oracle connect by description
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315
recursive CTE in postresql
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html